# How to increase the selection by the side opposite to the cursor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If `b` and `c` are selected and the cursor is next to `c`, is there a command to select the line above (`a`)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ended up installing [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sandipchitale.exchange-selection-start-end) to exchange the position of the cursor from one side of the selection to the other